# Accessing classes from separate modules

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with the following basic setup:

Root Project
  - employee-service
  - nomination-service

I need to access classes from employee-service in nomination-service, but am not able to get the dependencies down for some reason.

Here's the root project's `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'pair-project'

include 'applications/employee-service'
include 'applications/nomination-service'
```

Inside of the nomination-service `build.gradle` I have tried all the following (each dependency denotes one thing I've tried, they're not all present at the same time):

```
dependencies {
    project(':employee-service')
    project(':../../applications/employee-service')
    compile(':../employee-service')
    compile(':employee-service')
    compile('./applications/employee-service')
    compile('/employee-service')
}
```

All of these doesn't work for some reason or the other.The `project` ones generally tell me it can't find a project at that location. When I use `compile` it will usually build fine, but then can't find the import for the class I'm trying to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here, everything I've read online has generally suggested taking this approach, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Same error: `Project with path '...' could not be found in project ':applications/nomination-service'` The `...` in the path is replaced with just about anything I can think of to put into the `project` line (../employee-service, employee-service, ../../applications/employee-service.) I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but these exist only locally. I just saw some question on here that said I may need to manually compile the JAR file and include that since it isn't published online.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right relative path to these projects? try to put 2 dots instead of 1

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from me, I just double checked the two dots doesn't work. I

Comment: I can have a look tomorrow when I will be at work, right now I don't see the problem. If no one answers you till tomorrow, I will put the answer

Comment: One last try. Put " : " in the include and delete it from the project line. Follow this guide: https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/

Comment: Hmmm, might I need to re-organize my folders? Not sure why it would make a difference, but I have an `applications` folder that then houses my dependencies, so instead of `Root Project -> Dependency -> build.gradle`, I have `Root Project -> Applications -> Dependency -> build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

The `applications/nominations-service/build.gradle` should be:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':applications/employee-service')
}
```

Generally, [from here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html) dependencies require a *configuration* and one or more items with a *dependency notation*. In this case, *compile* is the configuration and we are using a [project dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_project_dependency). All of your examples only had one, but not both.